# Remove an already-registered $state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was surprised to learn that ui-router shares state across modules.

That's ok, but for our development environment I'd like to clear all the application states and start from scratch.

It's not convenient to avoid defining them in the first case just for our test environment, because the state definition is mixed in with all the other application loading, and we'd like to be sure that the application dependencies are describe the same way in all environments.

So can I clear, or remove one-by-one, the already defined states?

```
.config( function($stateProvider) {
  // TODO: get rid of $state definitions from the app, we don't want them here
}
```

Comment: Found this. "on roadmap": https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1095

Comment: I think you can overwrite states. So you could replace the state with a URL that will never be matched.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia the problem is there isn't a good way to remove it from the  `$urlRouterProvider`. If there was I think this would already be a feature as it's been requested many times.

Comment: possibly looking at this backwards... perhaps you want to look at conditional configurations depending on environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. `ui-router` uses `ng-router` and `ng-router` does not expose the routes until after the provider is compiled. Meaning you wouldn't be able to remove states/routes until the app is configured. Which I don't think they will accept a PR.

**Edit:**

In response to the comment made. The routes objects used by the `$routerProvider` is available and you can remove routes.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L451

`delete $route.routes['/'];`

But the states object used by the `$stateProvider` **is not** available.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/a7d25c6/src/state.js

So `ui-router` would need to be modified to be able to remove states after config. OR `ng-router` would need to be modified to be able to remove routes during config.

Comment: Can I remove them *after* the app is configured?

Comment: You are able to remove routes but without a modified version of ui-router you cannot access the states object to remove that. That needs to be provided to the `$state` injectable.

Comment: Yeah... It's the states from $state.get() I want to get rid of. Oh well, good to know it needs a fork to get done. Thanks Micah!

Answer (score 2):

With `angular-ui-router` starting from Version 1.0.0 (currently in `rc1` version) it is now possible to properly remove states.

Inject `$stateRegistry` (runtime) or `$stateRegistryProvider` (config) and call the `deregister()` method.

Here the detailed [API](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_stateregistry), implemented with [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/44579ecbafe15ad587dc341ba4a80af78b62bdaa) commit